# C++ getpeername returns 0.0.0.0:0

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, ip, port

I'm trying to get IP and Port of client, connected to the server socket. I pass the following function client socket file descriptor, but it returns 0.0.0.0:0
This drives me crazy, but **sometimes** it returns something like 248.127.0.0:24870...
What am I doing wrong?

PS returned address length is 16. Result returned by function is 0. No errors occur.

```
void    SocketServer::Log ( int socketFD , string message )
{
    struct sockaddr                     address;
    socklen_t                           addressLength;
    struct sockaddr_in*                 addressInternet;
    string                              ip;
    int                                 port;

    int result = getpeername ( socketFD , &address , &addressLength );
    cout << "Address length is " << addressLength << "     Return is " <<  result << "\n";
    addressInternet = (struct sockaddr_in*)&address;

    ip = inet_ntoa ( addressInternet->sin_addr );
    port = ntohs ( addressInternet->sin_port );

    cout << "Socket FD is " << socketFD << " " << ip << ":" << port << " " <<  message << "\n";
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set `addressLength` before calling `getpeername`. You need:

```
addressLength = sizeof(address);
```

As the documentation says:

> The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small

Comment: thanks in advance! Worked fine for me. I just can't get one idea. Why is this function designed this way? Why should **I** calculate the size of address, why can't the function calculate it?

Comment: The function does calculate the size of the address. But it needs to know that your buffer is big enough to hold the whole address. Remember, `getpeername` is protocol-neutral. New protocols, that require larger buffers, may be added after your code is written. Copying an address into a buffer that isn't large enough to hold it could be catastrophic.

Comment: But I pass the function a pointer to my buffer. So, why can't the function look itself if it's big enough or not and make some actions depending on this calculation?

Comment: There's no way to look at a buffer and tell how big it is. How would you know what was the end of the buffer?

Comment: The confusion probably stems from sizeof(my_array) == size of array in bytes. The compiler knows how big your array is, because it knows what you declared it as. But with sizeof(ptr_to_my_array) == sizeof(void*) there's no way to tell how much can safely be written to the pointed at buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a full `sockaddr_in` instance to `getpeername()` instead of a `sockaddr` instance, and you need to set the `addressLength` before calling `getpeername()`:

```
void SocketServer::Log ( int socketFD , string message )       
{       
    struct sockaddr_in                  address = {0};       
    socklen_t                           addressLength = sizeof(address);       
    string                              ip;       
    int                                 port;       

    int result = getpeername ( socketFD , (struct sockaddr*) &address , &addressLength );       
    cout << "Address length is " << addressLength << "     Return is " <<  result << endl;       

    ip = inet_ntoa ( address.sin_addr );       
    port = ntohs ( address.sin_port );       

    cout << "Socket FD is " << socketFD << " " << ip << ":" << port << " " <<  message << endl;       
};
```

Comment: Apparently inet_ntoa is deprecated these days and one should use inet_ntop instead.

Comment: @Scre yes, but that doesn't change what I said about the `getpeername()` parameters. And if you are going to make the change to use `inet_ntop()` (you could alternatively use `getnameinfo()` instead) then you should also make the change to use `sockaddr_storage` instead of `sockaddr_in`, otherwise there is no point in using protocol-agnostic functions.